# Django project architecture guidance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on a project and I'm not sure what my next step is to be or how to best achieve the result that I want.

**What I would like to do**

Create a quiz-like app where I can add questions and answers, and have users select the right options either through multiple-choice or text input and have the answer validated against the correct question

**What I currently have**

I have a Django setup of the following

```
from django.db import models

class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam)


class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**This is what I currently can do**

- I can use the admin panel to add new questions, answers and exams
- I can pass the new data to render them on a template and therefore the website, so if I add a new question I can have it appear on the website
- I also know how to create a form that passes data to the server and adds new data to the database without having to use the admin panel
- I know how to pass data to a template from the database

**What I don't know how to do**

- I don't know how to display the answers in a way that allows users to interact with them. For example, do I use HTML5 forms, do I have use JavaScript, do I use the Django forms, do I use the Django multipleChoice class?

For starters, if I am able to output the Answers to the Question in a multiple-choice like field that would be a nice start, where the server would return either "Correct" or incorrect based on whether the question is incorrect or not.

**What I think might be related to what I need to know**

- Do I have to use the Django REST framework for this?

Django version: 1.11

Answer (score 0):

If you just show the question and answers as a list and user(s) will answer it (without store the answers and result) ~> just show the list and when user click submit ~> use **Ajax** to send data (which one you save is as param or json) to server and check the answers in **views.py** then response the result content to user(s)

If you want to do more than that like:
Multi select answers, save answer as template, save answer in database, save the result, Re-use the answer (1 answer belong to many question)... You need to learn more think like:

Manytomany field, Data flow,... just all the basic thing in [Django tutoria](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/#django-documentation)l

Comment: Ok thanks, I was thinking something along the lines of that too. However, do I use a HTML5 form or a Django form to do that? Can they both be used together?

Comment: What ever you want. in my case:
i create like tutorial, make some .html file in template and give it data to display. About the form, juts some view to select, you can create it and handle yourself or use django support. i like to make it mysefl